# failed to open stream: Permission denied in Controller

Tags: php, shopping-cart

```
 Warning: require(/srv/homes/CB/vitalie.rosescu/wwwroot/20172018/ma2/bxl/view/orders/cart.php): `failed to open stream: Permission denied` in /srv/homes/CB/vitalie.rosescu/wwwroot/20172018/ma2/bxl/controller/Controller.php on line 30
```

I can't seem to open my shopping cart.
My othPHPphp files like index, a tour page and a detail page work fine. I can add items into my shopping cart but I can't visit it. De page can't be found.
Does anyone know what the problem could be?

the file looks like this

```
<?php

class Controller {

  public $route;
  protected $viewVars = array();

  public function filter() {
    call_user_func(array($this, $this->route['action']));
  }

  public function render() {
    $this->createViewVarWithContent();
    $this->renderInLayout();
    if (!empty($_SESSION['info'])) {
      unset($_SESSION['info']);
    }
    if (!empty($_SESSION['error'])) {
      unset($_SESSION['error']);
    }
  }

  public function set($variableName, $value) {
    $this->viewVars[$variableName] = $value;
  }

  private function createViewVarWithContent() {
    extract($this->viewVars, EXTR_OVERWRITE);
    ob_start();
    require __DIR__ . '/../view/' . strtolower($this->route['controller']) . '/' . $this->route['action'] . '.php';
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    $this->set('content', $content);
  }

  private function renderInLayout() {
    extract($this->viewVars, EXTR_OVERWRITE);
    include __DIR__ . '/../view/layout.php';
  }

}
```

Comment: Sounds like a file permission issue. Check if the file's owner and permissions are the same as your other files.